# Summing a finite prefix of an infinite series

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, precision, numeric, numerical-methods

The number `π` can be calculated with the following infinite series sum:

[image: Formula]

I want to define a Haskell function `roughlyPI` that, given a natural number `k`, calculates the series sum from `0` to the `k` value.

Example: `roughlyPi 1000` (or whatever) => `3.1415926535897922`

What I did was this (in VS Code):

```
roughlyPI :: Double -> Double 
roughlyPI 0 = 2 
roughlyPI n = e1/e2 + (roughlyPI (n-1)) 
         where 
             e1 = 2**(n+1)*(factorial n)**2 
             e2 = factorial (2*n +1) 
             factorial 0 = 1 
             factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)
```

but it doesn't really work....

```
*Main> roughlyPI 100 
NaN
```

I don't know what's wrong. I'm new to Haskell, by the way.

All I really want is to be able to type in a number that will give me `PI` at the end. It can't be that hard...

Comment: Why do you think that there is something wrong?

Comment: Because in VS Code, it doesnt really work....

*Main> roughlyPI 100
NaN

Comment: Computing the factorials then dividing them results in `Infinity / Infinity` very quickly, which is why you get `NaN`. You should essentially intersperse multiplication and division, e.g. `(1 * 2 * 3 * 4) / (5 * 6 * 7 * 8)` should be calculated as `1 / 5 * 2 / 6 * 3 / 7 * 4 / 8`.

Comment: Firstly, it's better if you make a more descriptive title (explain roughly what you're trying to do), and secondly you should explain what's wrong with the code **in the post** instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, we need to avoid large divisions and instead intersperse smaller divisions within the factorials. We use `Double` for representing PI but even `Double` has its limits. For instance `1 / 0 == Infinity` and `(1 / 0) / (1 / 0) == Infinity / Infinity == NaN`.

Luckily, we can use algebra to simplify the formula and hopefully delay the blowup of our `Double`s. By dividing within our factorial the numbers don't grow too unwieldy too quickly.

[image: f1]

[image: f2]

[image: f3]

This solution will calculate `roughlyPI 1000`, but it fails on 1023 with `NaN` because `2 ^ 1024 :: Double == Infinity`. Note how each iteration of `fac` has a division as well as a multiplication to help keep the numbers from blowing up. If you are trying to approximate PI with a computer, I believe there are better algorithms, but I tried to keep it as conceptually close to your attempt as possible.

```
roughlyPI :: Integer -> Double
roughlyPI 0 = 2
roughlyPI k = e + roughlyPI (k - 1)
  where
    k' = fromIntegral k
    e = 2 ** (k' + 1) * fac k / (2 * k' + 1)
      where
        fac 1 = 1 / (k' + 1)
        fac p = (fromIntegral p / (k' + fromIntegral p)) * fac (p - 1)
```

We can do better than having a blowup of `Double` after 1000 by doing computations with [`Rationals`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Rational) then converting to `Double` with [`realToFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac) (credit to @leftaroundabout):

```
roughlyPI' :: Integer -> Double
roughlyPI' = realToFrac . go
  where
    go 0 = 2
    go k = e + go (k - 1)
      where
        e = 2 ^ (k + 1) * fac k / (2 * fromIntegral k + 1)
          where
            fac 1 = 1 % (k + 1)
            fac p = (p % (k + p)) * fac (p - 1)
```

For further reference see [Wikipedia page on approximations of PI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)

P.S. Sorry for the bulky equations, stackoverflow does not support LaTex

Answer (score 5):

First note that your code actually *works*:

```
*Main> roughlyPI 91
3.1415926535897922
```

The problem, as was already said, is that when you try to make the approximation better, the factorial terms become too big to be representable in double-precision floats. The simplest – albeit somewhat brute-force – way to fix that is to do all the computation in *rational* arithmetic instead. Because numerical operations in Haskell are polymorphic, this works with almost the same code as you have, only the `**` operator can't be used since that allows fractional exponents (which are in general irrational). Instead, you should use *integer* exponents, which is anyway the conceptually right thing. That requires a few `fromIntegral`:

```
roughlyPI :: Integer -> Rational 
roughlyPI 0 = 2 
roughlyPI n = e1/e2 + (roughlyPI (n-1)) 
         where 
             e1 = 2^(n+1)*fromIntegral (factorial n^2)
             e2 = fromIntegral . factorial $ 2*n + 1
             factorial 0 = 1 
             factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)
```

This now works also for much higher degrees of approximation, although it takes a long time to carry around the giant fractions involved:

```
*Main> realToFrac $ roughlyPI 1000
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 4):

The way to go in such cases is to calculate the ratio of consecutive terms and calculate the terms by rolling multiplications of the ratios:

```
-- 1. -------------
pi1 n = Sum { k = 0 .. n } T(k)
  where
  T(k) = 2^(k+1)(k!)^2 / (2k+1)!

-- 2. -------------
ts2 = [ 2^(k+1)*(k!)^2 / (2k+1)! | k <- [0..] ]
pis2 = scanl1 (+) ts2
pi2 n = pis2 !! n

-- 3. -------------
T(k)  = 2^(k+1)(k!)^2 / (2k+1)!
T(k+1) = 2^(k+2)((k+1)!)^2 / (2(k+1)+1)!
       = T(k) 2 (k+1)^2 / (2k+2) (2k+3)
       = T(k)   (k+1)^2 / ( k+1) (2k+3)
       = T(k)   (k+1)   /        (k+1 + k+2)
       = T(k)           /        (1 + (k+2)/(k+1))
       = T(k)           /        (2 + 1    /(k+1))

-- 4. -------------
ts4 = scanl (/) 2 [ 2 + 1/(k+1) | k <- [0..]] :: [Double]
pis4 = scanl1 (+) ts4
pi4 n = pis4 !! n
```

This way we share and reuse the calculations as much as possible. This leads to the most efficient code, hopefully leading to the smallest cumulative numerical error. The formula also turned out to be exceptionally simple, and could even be simplified further as `ts5 = scanl (/) 2 [ 2 + recip k | k <- [1..]]`.

Trying it out:

```
> pis2 = scanl1 (+) $ [ fromIntegral (2^(k+1))*fromIntegral (product[1..k])^2 / 
                         fromIntegral (product[1..(2*k+1)]) | k <- [0..] ] :: [Double]

> take 8 $ drop 30 pis2
[3.1415926533011587,3.141592653447635,3.141592653519746,3.1415926535552634,
 3.141592653572765,3.1415926535813923,3.141592653585647,3.141592653587746]

> take 8 $ drop 90 pis2
[3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN]

> take 8 $ drop 30 pis4
[3.1415926533011587,3.141592653447635,3.141592653519746,3.1415926535552634,
 3.141592653572765,3.1415926535813923,3.141592653585647,3.141592653587746]

> take 8 $ drop 90 pis4
[3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,
 3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922,3.1415926535897922]

> pis4 !! 1000
3.1415926535897922
```